# Session Bean and JSP Session

Tags: jsp, session, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am reading about EJB Session Bean. I have worked mostly on spring and on website we keep the session in normal session object. Documents of session bean says that if i have a shopping cart, i use session bean? is that mean i don't need to take care of session on JSP level? and can this session bean also be used to maintain the user session.

I don't agree what i write last in above paragraph. Isn't it repetition of code and extra use of memory.

Please explain this concept which i am not getting at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A session in a Servlet, is maintained by the Servlet Container through the HttpSession object, that is acquired through the request object. You cannot really instantiate a new HttpSession object, and it doesn't contains any business logic, but is more of a place where to store objects.

A session in EJB is maintained using the SessionBeans. You design beans that can contain business logic, and that can be used by the clients. You have two different session beans: Stateful and Stateless. The first one is somehow connected with a single client. It maintains the state for that client, can be used only by that client and when the client "dies" then the session bean is "lost".

A Stateless Session Bean doesn't maintain any state and there is no guarantee that the same client will use the same stateless bean, even for two calls one after the other. The lifecycle of a Stateless Session EJB is slightly different from the one of a Stateful Session EJB. Is EJB Container's responsability to take care of knowing exactly how to track each session and redirect the request from a client to the correct instance of a Session Bean. The way this is done is vendor dependant, and is part of the contract.

Comment: More reading on serverside http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=552

Comment: thank you sandeep but then what's the benefit for using session bean in a application, i have been storing user session in HTTPSession object. If i am using EJBs, why would i be using sessionbean and what's the benefit of doing so and whats the problems of following this approach.

Comment: The thing about beans is that you move your business logic out of your servlet. This is a major benefit as you can now reuse the logic across servlets and EJB can interact with a whole range of other technologies.

Comment: I have stopped using Session beans ages back, since its more of a overhead. Advantages of using session bean was , It supports transaction service, security service, life cycle management, RMI, instance cache; thread safe etc. so one need not to write code for these services.Both web based and non-web based clients can use it.Multiple operations for a single http request can be processed.

Comment: so basically EJBs simple act as a service layer as we implement business logic in spring framework. thanks alot for clearing my concepts.

Answer (score 0):

So a EJB can be defined as server-side components that encapsulate business logic and take care of transactions and security. They also have an integrated stack for messaging, scheduling, remote access, web service endpoints (SOAP and REST), dependency injection, component life cycle, AOP with interceptors, and so on.

There are three types of Sessions EJB's:

1. **Stateless:** The session bean contains no conversational state between methods, and any
   instance can be used for any client.
2. **Stateful:** The session bean contains conversational state, which must be retained
   across methods for a single user.
3. **Singleton:** A single session bean is shared between clients and supports concurrent
   access.

In a web application you would typically use stateless beans to do a listing of products. YOu would then use a stateful bean to store products in a shopping cart.

Hopefully this helps a little bit.